# Adding Query HTML/PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, html

Okay, so i really need help about the add query. I don't know what i did wrong. Please help. This is the code for my update.php

```
<form action="updateprocess.php" method="POST">
    Description         <input type="text" id="desc" name="desc">
    SWL.Tonne           <input type="text" id="swltonne" name="swltonne">
    Inches              <input type="text" id="inches" name="inches">
    Model               <input type="text" id="model" name="model">
    SafetyFactor        <input type="text" id="safetyfactor" name="safetyfactor">   
    Date/LPO            <input type="text" id="datelpo" name="datelpo"> 
    Manufacturer        <input type="text" id="manu" name="manu">   
    Certificate.Number  <input type="text" id="cnumber" name="cnumber"> 
    Opening.Stock       <input type="text" id="opstock" name="opstock"> 
    January             <input type="text" id="jan" name="jan"> 
    February            <input type="text" id="feb" name="feb"> 
    March               <input type="text" id="mar" name="mar">
    April               <input type="text" id="apr" name="apr">
    May                 <input type="text" id="may" name="may">
    June                <input type="text" id="jun" name="jun">
    July                <input type="text" id="jul" name="jul">
    August              <input type="text" id="aug" name="aug">
    September           <input type="text" id="sep" name="sep">
    October             <input type="text" id="oct" name="oct">
    November            <input type="text" id="nov" name="nov">
    December            <input type="text" id="dec" name="dec">
    Total.Used          <input type="text" id="totuse" name="totuse">
    Available.Balance   <input type="text" id="avaibal" name="avaibal">
    Minimumm.Stock      <input type="text" id="minstocks" name="minstocks">
    FOQ/FOI             <input type="text" id="foqi" name="foqi">
    Comment             <input type="text" id="comm" name="comm">
</div>
        <div class="submit-container"> <input class="submit-button" 
type="submit" value="Add">
        <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Clear" /></div>
</form>
```

and this is the updateprocess.php I really dont know what to do. My database name is franklinoffshore and i used mysqli

```
<?php
        $desc           = $_POST['desc'];
        $swltonne       = $_POST['swltonne'];
        $inches         = $_POST['inches'];
        $model          = $_POST['model'];
        $safetyfactor   = $_POST['safetyfactor'];
        $datelpo        = $_POST['datelpo'];
        $manu           = $_POST['manu'];
        $cnumber        = $_POST['cnumber'];
        $opstock        = $_POST['opstock'];
        $jan            = $_POST['jan'];
        $feb            = $_POST['feb'];
        $mar            = $_POST['mar'];
        $apr            = $_POST['apr'];
        $may            = $_POST['may'];
        $jun            = $_POST['jun'];
        $jul            = $_POST['jul'];
        $aug            = $_POST['aug'];
        $sep            = $_POST['sep'];
        $oct            = $_POST['oct'];
        $nov            = $_POST['nov'];
        $dec            = $_POST['dec'];
        $totuse         = $_POST['totuse'];
        $avaibal        = $_POST['avaibal'];
        $minstocks      = $_POST['minstocks'];
        $foqi           = $_POST['foqi'];
        $comm           = $_POST['comm'];

//connect to the serverand database

    $franklinoffshore = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","franklinoffshore");


//query the database
{   
    $result = mysqli_query($franklinoffshore, "INSERT INTO inventory_hooks(Description,SWLTonne,Inches,Model,SafetyFactor,DateLPO,Manufacturer,CertificateNumber,OpeningStocks,January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December,TotalUsed,AvailableBalance,MinimumStocks,FoqFoi,Comment) 
    VALUES('$description','$swltonne','$inches','$model','$safetyfactor','$datelpo','$manufacturer','$cnumber','$opstock','$jan','$feb','$mar','$apr','$may','$jun','$jul','$aug','$sep','$oct','$nov','$dec','$totuse','$avaibal','$minstocks','$foqi','$comm')");     

}
?>
```

It keeps saying that Lines (too many lines) are Undefined Index. Or was i missing something?

PS: Its an inventory list thats why its toooo much.

Comment: 1/ Are you sure each `input name` is the same that your `$_POST['...']` name? 2/ Are you sure each value are not null? 3/ Are you sure in your INSERT you have each name with the right value? 4/ You should use prepare statement to avoid sql injection :)

Comment: yes everything is correct actually its the same with everything...what should i do with the prepare statement? help

Comment: Here is some doc about it : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php :)
The `Undefined Index` problem is because some of the index you use are not defined = some may be wrong ! Try to check which one return an error and try to correct it, can't help you more we can't test your code and we can't see the error message ! Add it to your question, maybe it will help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$franklinoffshore = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","franklinoffshore");

$desc           = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore, $_POST['desc']);
$swltonne       = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['swltonne']);
$inches         = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['inches']);
$model          = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['model']);
$safetyfactor   = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['safetyfactor']);
$datelpo        = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['datelpo']);
$manu           = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['manu']);
$cnumber        = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['cnumber']);
$opstock        = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['opstock']);
$jan            = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['jan']);
$feb            = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['feb']);
$mar            = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['mar']);
$apr            = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['apr']);
$may            = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['may']);
$jun            = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['jun']);
$jul            = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['jul']);
$aug            = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['aug']);
$sep            = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['sep']);
$oct            = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['oct']);
$nov            = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['nov']);
$dec            = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['dec']);
$totuse         = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['totuse']);
$avaibal        = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['avaibal']);
$minstocks      = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['minstocks']);
$foqi           = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['foqi']);
$comm           = mysqli_real_escape_string($franklinoffshore,$_POST['comm']);

//connect to the serverand database



$result = mysqli_query($franklinoffshore,
"INSERT INTO inventory_hooks
(Description,SWLTonne,Inches,Model,
SafetyFactor,DateLPO,Manufacturer,
CertificateNumber,OpeningStocks,
January,February,March,April,May,
June,July,August,September,October,
November,December,TotalUsed,AvailableBalance,
MinimumStocks,FoqFoi,Comment) VALUES
('$description','$swltonne',
'$inches','$model','$safetyfactor',
'$datelpo','$manufacturer','$cnumber',
'$opstock','$jan','$feb','$mar','$apr',
'$may','$jun','$jul','$aug','$sep','$oct',
'$nov','$dec','$totuse','$avaibal','$minstocks',
'$foqi','$comm')");

if($result) {
 echo "It works";
 }
?>
```